# Styling TextField focus state in NativeScript via CSS

Tags: css, focus, textfield, nativescript

Is there any way to control a textfield focus state in nativescript?
So when the user tap into a textfield and when they type in it, its style is different, for example differenct border, or background, all this only via css, or adding a class that cak be styled.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Currently you cannot do this easily. Here’s the feature request to make this possible: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2181 (feel free to add a vote there to help raise its priority). There’s definitely a way to accomplish this task with native iOS and Android code, but it’ll take a bit of digging to figure out exactly how.

Answer (score 2):

From this page [Chapter 6—Accessing Native APIs](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-6)

> At the time of this writing, NativeScript doesn’t expose a way to
>   style a text field’s hint color through CSS—although there is an open
>   issue requesting the feature—however, both iOS and Android have ways
>   to accomplish this task, and with NativeScript you have direct access
>   to these native APIs.

But you can still achieve this with the sample code on the page, but not css.

Maybe this will be part of 2.4 and there is a recognized issue on this already.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. As I can see, here they are talking about placeholders. Unfortunately I read this issue, but I wonder if the focus style can be done. So not the hint color, but the textfield itself can be styling, when the user tapped into it.